# A great deal of advertising/advertisement is now done as we surf the internet

Tags: grammar

which word is correct to be used in the sentence?- advertising or advertisement?
And why may I ask?

> A great deal of advertising/advertisement is now done as we surf the internet

When I checked the oxford advanced dictionary, both words (advertising & advertisement) can have meanings that refer to the 'activity of advertising'.So that means both can be right in the above sentence. But a Cambridge textbook says its advertising; not advertisement. And the reason is not given! Why? Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1):

*Advertising* is the general concept of marketing through media sources.  An *advertisement* is a specific example of this kind of marketing.

> My marketing manager says we should **advertise** more in the local newspaper
>
> My marketing manager says we should post more **advertisements** in the local newspaper.

So either of these is correct:

> There's a lot of **advertising** on the web (the general concept)
>
> There are a lot of **advertisements** on the web. (specific examples of the concept)

Comment: They're pretty much interchangeable in AmE, but singular **advertisement** (referring to the general practice of publicizing products and services) seems to have enjoyed a lot more currency in the mid 20th century than it has now.

Answer (score 0):

In American English, **advertisement** nowadays refers abstractly to the *practice* of publicizing products and services:

> Advertisement of goods and services is necessary when word-of-mouth would prove ineffective.

and  **advertising** refers either to the business of publicizing products and services:

> She was looking for a job in advertising.

or to  ads collectively:

> We decided to monetize the online version of the newspaper by subjecting visitors to lots of advertising. It was either that, or a paywall.

In the mid 20th century, countable **advertisement** was just the long form of today's **ad**.

> There were advertisements for cigarettes in most popular magazines.